# Change the status of toggle using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, bootstrap-4

I am trying to change the status of toggle switch using jquery but not success.
this is the code of jquery

```
$('#bandwidthcap').checked='false';
```

and I tried using this way

```
$('#bandwidthcap').attr('checked','false')
```

this is the code of html

```
<input type="checkbox"  name="bandwidthcap" id="bandwidthcap" class="switchery" data-color="primary"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the .prop() function:

```js
$('#bandwidthcap').prop("checked", true)
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="bandwidthcap" id="bandwidthcap" class="switchery" data-color="primary" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```